# Need xpath to locate 2 buttons with almost same properties for using in Selenium automation script

Tags: button, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Both these buttons have almost similar ID (the number on the ID may change and so is not reliable)
Both have same classes 
They both reside under the same parent
Except for the span nothing is different

All the UI elements of the application I am trying to locate and build events on Using Selenium are similar to the below piece...

Can anyone please suggest how I can locate these buttons preferable with xpath?

```
<div id="button-1749" class="x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-  small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon x-item-disabled x-disabled x-btn-disabled x-btn-default-toolbar-small-disabled" style="margin: 0pt; left: 1563px; top: 0px;">
<em id="button-1749-btnWrap" class="">
<button id="button-1749-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button"    hidefocus="true" type="button" aria-disabled="true" disabled="">
<span id="button-1749-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="">Delete Selected</span>
<span id="button-1749-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon x-hide-display">&nbsp;</span>
</button>
</em>
</div>
<div id="button-1750" class="x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-noicon" style="margin: 0pt; left: 1654px; top: 0px;">
<em id="button-1750-btnWrap" class="">
<button id="button-1750-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button"    tabindex="1" hidefocus="true" type="button">
<span id="button-1750-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="">New Title</span>
<span id="button-1750-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon x-hide-display">&nbsp;</span>
</button>
</em>
</div>
```

Comment: I figured out the xpath I need.. its..      //button[contains(@class, "x-btn-center")]/span[./text()='New Title'] but now I am stuck again.  I have three of these nested under 3 different div's. Now I need figure out how to get descendants of a particular div (that has a unique ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look for the elements under a specific div, you can use `descendent` axis.

Example:

```
//div[@id='your div']/descendant::button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/span[text()='Delete Selected']"
```

This will give you Deleted Selected button that is within the div with id 'your div'.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use GetElements (opposed to GetElement) and this will return a List of elements that match your search criteria. Then, providing the order the buttons appear on the page never changes, you may use this List to access the button you want every time by using the associated index.

Eg.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> buttons = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("YOUR XPATH HERE"));
//If it's the 3rd button that matches your criteria
buttons[2].Click(); //or whatever you want with this button :)
```

Comment: I would prefer to use Descendants but your idea is good too. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work in your case:

```
locator = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/em/button/span[contains(text(),'Delete Selected')]")
```

You can do similar way in case of another element.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the xpath part as I commented on my first post (//button[contains(@class, "x-btn-center")]/span[./text()='New Title']). The problem I had was there are 3 such buttons in the DOM I needed the Descendants input Justin Ko gave above

Answer (score 0):

though xpath is a desired locator per your question, there are documented speed differences between xpath and css selector, here's one example: http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/05/why-css-locators-are-the-way-to-go-vs-xpath/.  to locate those elements via css selector, use the following, python example

```
els = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[id^=button]
for eachel in els:
   eachel.click()
```

Comment: I have done this trade of comparison between using XPath and CSS and decided to go with XPATH as it is more stable and less likely  to change (at least in the application I am trying to automate). I would prefer the tests to be more reliable than faster. Thank you for the useful link and reply.

Comment: to me, my locator method is more reliable as the buttons will probably always have an id of button[num], xpaths are brittle as if you add another element in the chain, it will break as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own xpath if the xpath of 2 elements are same

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text),'New Title')]")).click;
```